# Randomize the layout of a set of existing images with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom-manipulation

I have a grid of images (baseball and football teams), with names associated with them (like captions).
What I'm trying to do is randomize the placement of the images with the names so they appear at different spots of the grid.
I can get the images and names to display (the names come from a `textarea` and are stored into a names `array`) just fine, but as soon as I hit the <kbd>random</kbd> button, the `img.src` disappears, leaving me with blank spots.
The names still randomize though and work fine.

This is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>sports</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Sports Random</h1>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" id="parent">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      </div>
      <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
      <div id="buttonGroup">
        <button id="random">Random</button>
        <button id="baseball">Baseball</button>
        <button id="football">Football</button>
        <button id="reset">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
bGroup.addEventListener("click", function images(e) {
  tDisplay.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 1; i < names.length; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var newImg = document.createElement("img");
    var userName = document.createElement("p");
    newDiv.className = "col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2"
    newDiv.appendChild(newImg);
    newDiv.appendChild(userName);
    userName.textContent = names[Math.random() * i | 0];
    if (e.target.id === "baseball") {
      newImg.src = "images\\baseball\\team" + i + ".jpg";
    } else if (e.target.id === "football") {
      newImg.src = "images\\football\\team" + i + ".gif";
    }
    tDisplay.appendChild(newDiv);
  };

});

// random the images
random.addEventListener("click", function random() {
  for (var i = 0; i < tDisplay.children.length; i++) {
    tDisplay.appendChild(tDisplay.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
    tDisplay.getElementsByTagName("p")[Math.random() * i | 0].textContent =
      names[Math.random() * i | 0];
  }
});
```

Right now the buttons on my page are in a `div` group (bGroup) and then I delegate events depending on which button is clicked.
I had this working when I had separate functions for "baseball" and "football" images; just trying to reduce code.
The <kbd>random</kbd> button is included in the button group but I kept it separate just for the sake of organization; kind of wondering if that is good practice or not?

If possible I would like any answers strictly in JavaScript.

Comment: `newImg.src = "images\\baseball\\team"` and the like should probably be `newImg.src = "images/baseball/team"`. Please try and feedback with results.

Comment: Incidentally: where a JavaScript question concerns the manipulation of the DOM, it would be ideal to add some example HTML to build a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i have added my html

Comment: Did you try changing the `img.src` relative path strings as I suggested in my comment above?

Comment: missed that comment some how but i just tried it. it is the same result. the images will display initially, but when i hit the random button, the images disappear.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification; a possible issue eliminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Interference

The cause of the problem is that your <kbd>Random</kbd> button has its own `"click"` event listener whilst being a child of `bGroup` which **also** has a `"click"` event listener.
The exact process that results in empty clones is kind of irrelevant, but could be examined (if interested) by use `console.log()`.

When you click <kbd>Random</kbd>, you trigger both the randomization of the contents of `tDisplay` **and** the initialization/creation of `<div><img><p></p></div>` children.

You have two options:

- Either [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) of the `"click"` event in the unique listener attached to <kbd>Random</kbd>.
- Or include the randomization functionality in the function triggered by a `"click"` on `bGroup`.

I have built a simplified version of your code below, using the second option stated above.

- Since the randomization code `Math.random() * i | 0` is [used many times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), I've created a function to return the *random* result of any number parsed through it.
- The [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) declarations at the top of the JS are to store values that will **never** change and that are repeatedly used throughout the script.

  > The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its parameters) can be altered.
- I've used [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of `var` where suitable, since it's less leaky.

  > `let` allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike the `var` keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope.
- I chose to use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop to iterate through `names`, but retained the `for` loop to handle the randization.
  Each has its own merits.
- The [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) called by `forEach()` uses two arguments; `n` and `i`, where `n` is the `name` on each loop, and `i` is the `index` of the `name` (a loop counter).
- I also chose to use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead of [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) for brevity.
- Those changes have benefits, but the only significant change is in moving the `"click"` handling for <kbd>Random</kbd> into the handler for clicks on `bGroup`.

Be aware that the randomization may not change the display every time (the nature of *random*), but keep clicking and you'll see that it does in fact work; a longer `names` `Array` (and thus more images) would likely randomize more noticeably.

```js
const tDisplay = document.querySelector( ".container" ),
      bGroup = document.querySelector( "#buttonGroup" ),
      names = [ "foo", "bar", "baz", "qux" ];

function randIndex( i ) {
  return ( Math.random() * i | 0 );
}

bGroup.addEventListener( "click", function( evt ) {
  let trg = evt.target.id;
  if ( trg !== "random" ) {
    tDisplay.innerHTML = "";
    names.forEach( ( n, i ) => {
      let newDiv = document.createElement( "div" ),
          newImg = document.createElement( "img" ),
          userName = document.createElement( "p" );
      //newDiv.className = "col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2";
      newDiv.appendChild( newImg );
      newDiv.appendChild( userName );
      userName.textContent = names[ randIndex( i ) ];
      if ( trg === "sports" ) {
        newImg.src = "https://lorempixel.com/100/70/sports/" + i;
      } else if ( trg === "cats") {
        newImg.src = "https://lorempixel.com/100/70/cats/" + i;
      }
      tDisplay.appendChild( newDiv );
    } );
  } else {
    for ( let i = 0; i < tDisplay.children.length; i++ ) {
      tDisplay.appendChild( tDisplay.children[ randIndex( i ) ] );
      tDisplay.querySelectorAll( "p" )[ randIndex( i ) ].textContent =
        names[ randIndex( i ) ];
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1, p {
  margin: .5em 0;
}
#buttonGroup {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.container div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Images Random</h1>
<div id="buttonGroup">
  <button id="random">Random</button>
  <button id="sports">Sports</button>
  <button id="cats">Cats</button>
</div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: a little late, but thank you for this. i am not too far into my studies but i understand most of this code, but i have not seen this line specifically:

names.forEach( ( n, i ) =>

i know what a for each is, but just to clarify, is n the items in the array, and i the random number? i don't use them too often right now. also, a short summary of the const and let keywords would be nice but i can do that on my own.

Comment: [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is a handy way to iterate over arrays and other array-like lists (like node-lists). It is widely supported on arrays, but Internet Explorer won't allow it on node-lists. For IE we can use `[].slice.call( node-list ).forEach()` to convert the node-list into an array before calling `forEach()`. The next part is an [arrow function notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) where "`n`" is for "name" and "`i`" is for "index".

Comment: Ha! You edited while I was responding (it happens). I will gladly add more details to the answer, but would ask please, that you wait until tomorrow. I am quite desperately in need of sleep right now, and am making lots of mistakes. But very basically, `let` is a less intrusive way to declare a `var`, and `const` is a `var` that isn't variable.